# Adding items to an array

Tags: templating, array

Is it possible to insert items into specific positions in an array (rather than at the beginning or at the end), a bit like javascript splice? Say, if I wanted to add a value between items 2 and 3? Please note I want to add keys to the array rather than replace anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) and [`merge`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html), although it's not very pretty:

```
{% set myArray = ['a', 'b', 'd' ] %}
{% set myArray = myArray|slice(0,2)|merge(['c'])|merge(myArray|slice(2,myArray|length)) %}

{{ myArray|join(', ') }}
```

To explain what's happening above:

```
{% set myArray = ['a', 'b', 'd' ] %}
```

This just sets an array we can work with.

```
|slice(0,2)
```

The first slice filter "chops off" and returns the first two items in the original array (namely "a" and "b"). We do this because we want to add a value after the "b" (i.e. the second index).

```
|merge(['c'])
```

The first `merge` filter appends the value we want to add – the letter "c" – to the first two items. As `merge` is only able to merge arrays, we need to wrap the c in another array.

```
|merge(myArray|slice(2,myArray|length))
```

The inner part of this statement – the `slice` – pulls all the remaining values from the original array *after* the first two that we chopped off at the beginning, until the end of the array.

These values are then appended to the a, b and c with another `merge` statement.

```
{{ myArray|join(', ') }}
```

This is just a test, and will print `a, b, c, d`.

Comment: This worked thanks. Took me a while to get it, and had to break it down into shorter arrays and then join them altogether, as I wanted to add 4 and it was getting complicated! Hopefully this won't have too many implications performance-wise.

Comment: @Anna Happy you got it sorted! Twig quickly gets fairly unreadable when things gets a little complex – I added a more detailed explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you render the content of your array right after you inserted the elements? Yes? Then what about using a conditional checking the `loop.index` in your output loop to render your special inserted content at defined loop positions?

```
{% if loop.index == 2 %}
{% endif %}
```

```
{% if loop.index in [2, 5, 13] %}
{% endif %}
```